# Help with understanding: how does amsart class store the content of abstract for later use in \maketitle?

Tags: tex-core, abstract, amsart

I wish to understand how the `amsart` class managed to store the content of abstract for the later `\maketitle`, and why they demand the `abstract` environment to precede `\maketitle` (i.e. is there any advantage for this?). The definition looks like:

```
\newbox\abstractbox
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
  \ifx\maketitle\relax
    \ClassWarning{\@classname}{Abstract should precede
      \protect\maketitle\space in AMS document classes; reported}%
  \fi
  \global\setbox\abstractbox=\vtop \bgroup
    \normalfont\Small
    \list{}{\labelwidth\z@
      \leftmargin3pc \rightmargin\leftmargin
      \listparindent\normalparindent \itemindent\z@
      \parsep\z@ \@plus\p@
      \let\fullwidthdisplay\relax
    }%
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape\abstractname.]%
}{%
  \endlist\egroup
  \ifx\@setabstract\relax \@setabstracta \fi
}
```

I can't understand most of the code. The most attractive point for me is that: how does this code allow the presence of `\verb` in the abstract? (To create my own `abstract` environment, I tried to store the content in a macro, which fails to allow `\verb` in it; and at last I have no choice but to save the content in a file and input it later, which to me is undoubtedly a clumsy method)

Comment: They don't store it in a macro, which would have problems with `\verb`. Instead they store it in typeset form in a `\box`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMS requires the `abstract` environment to precede `\maketitle` because they want it to be part of the title block. This allows processing it in ways that depend on the final in-house document class that will be used.

It uses the TeX facility of storing typeset material in a vertical box, in this case `\vtop` (so the reference point will be at the first baseline in the material).

The syntax is

```
\setbox<box number>=\vtop{...}
```

where `{` and `}` need not be explicit braces, but can also be `\bgroup` and `\egroup` (implicit braces). Thus it's possible to start the `\vtop` in the `\begin` part of the environment, ending it in the `\end` part.

If `\begin{abstract}` is found after `\maketitle` an error is raised. In any case the `\vtop` is started, with storage bin `\abstractbox`. A `list` is started with appropriate settings. At `\end{abstract}` the `\endlist\egroup` tokens will finish the typesetting and store the typeset material in the bin.

The assignment is `\global` because the surrounding environment forms a group.

The disadvantages are that the material cannot be reprocessed (well, some form of reprocessing would be possible), but this is not of a concern, because the material has already been typeset in the desired format.

Afterwards, `\maketitle` can do `\box\abstractbox` to deliver the material in the current vertical list.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!